# Create all combains of array

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm Using C#.

I'm trying to create type of brute force keys.
I need to create 3 keys as follow:

```
([0-2,1-255,1-300],[0-2,1-255,1-300],[0-2,1-255,1-300])
```

To try to decrypt my message, If It Isn't correct to keep to the next key, I.e:

First Key: `([0,1,1],[0,1,1],[0,1,1])`
Second Key: `([0,1,1],[0,1,1],[0,1,2])`

What Is the best way to create the keys? Because anything that I'm trying Isn't working for me.

This is the struct of my key:

```
struct Key
{
    public byte code;
    public byte param;
    public uint len;
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look up Google for 'nested for-loops'. If you have difficulties applying nested for-loops to your given task, start with a simplified problem where you have keys/tuples of 2 parameters instead of 3...

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried even if it doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brute force approach would be to use 9 nested loops. 9 nested loops that's ugly. Since the three keys have the same structure, you could create an array containing all possible combinations of one key (3 x 255 x 300 = 229500). This is not too big. Then use three nested loops that select 3 keys within this array. Adavantage: You have to create the keys only once; this speed up checking combinations of the 3 keys.

```
const int N = 3 * 255 * 300;

// Create the keys
var keys = new Key[N];
int i = 0;
for (byte c = 0; c <= 2; c++) {
    for (int p = 1; p <= 255; p++) { // int because byte overflows after last loop.
        for (uint l = 1; l <= 300; l++) {
            keys[i++] = new Key { code = c, param = (byte)p, len = l };
        }
    }
}

// Select 3 keys
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    Key k1 = keys[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        Key k2 = keys[j];
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            Key k3 = keys[k];
            // Do something with k1, k2, k3
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if we declare `p` as `byte`, after what should be the last loop, where `p` is `255`, it is incremented again and becomes `0` (because [0 … 255] is the range of `byte`). Therefore, the loop would never terminate.

Since there are 229500<sup>3</sup> ≈ 1.2 * 10<sup>16</sup> (12 quadrillions in the American system) combinations, it could last several months until the programm finishes! Have a look at [How to: Write a Simple Parallel.For Loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx).

Overriding `ToString` in the struct `Key` simplyfies debugging.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"[{code},{param},{len}]";
}
```